# Problem with bootstrap carousel with razor

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I need help for a boostrap/razor project in school. I'm totaly new with those technologies. I've listen to youtube videos for help. I learn how to add bootstrap's libraires with libman in visual studio and i also copied the code from a video that show how the bootstrap' carousel is done. It doesnt work as expected the 3 pictures in my images folder are show one under of each other and there are show all the 3 at the same time instead of one picture slide each 2 seconds.

```html
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="2000" data="ride-carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item-active">  
                        <img src="~/images/page1.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                  </div>
                   <div class="item">
                        <img src="~/images/entraide-696x367.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                        <img src="~/images/page0AI.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                   </div> 
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```